# TextView onclick method crashes the application

Tags: java, android

I have a textView with OnClick method to navigate another activity. But, If i pressed that text it doesn't navigate. But If i used Button instead TextView, it works perfectly. Can't use OnClick method in TextView?

```
forgotpasstxt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtForgotpPass);

 /** Textview on click even.
         *
         */
        forgotpasstxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ChangePassword.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);}
  });
```

XML.Login

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:id="@+id/txtForgotpPass"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="perform_action"
        android:textColor="#ff3b5998"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnReset"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Please help, I do not understand why the application crashes once the user clicks on the forgot password link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the line:

```
android:onClick="perform_action"
```

this is because you are setting the TextView to do something `onClick` twice. In your XML you are saying to do a method called `perform_action` and in your code you are doing it correctly.

Since it's neater to use Java code for clicking and not XML I would suggest just removing the above line because the `OnClickListener` is correct.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

Remove this line:

```
android:onClick="perform_action"
```

You are setting the listener programmatically.

Comment: Will it work once this link is removed. Let me check and dubug the app.

Comment: Ok, let me know if works =) If you set the listener by code, you need to remove form XML and vice-versa

Comment: @J.Doe It says that you get a Null reference in your code. I have reviewed your code and do not find anything wrong, Can you re-generate your R.java. I'm curious about what caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

delete forgotpasstxt.setOnClickListener and add perform_action method

```
   public void perform_action(View view) {


    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ChangePassword.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
```

Comment: This should not be used as ClickListeners are preferred.